# Can not Join/Create more than 10 groups on XMPP server

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, muc

I have installed ejabber2 on server. Connecting from android via Smack library.

I am able to create and join 10 groups but can not create 11th group. If I leave one of the joined group then I can create new group and join it. But can not join the previous one.

Is there any limit set in ejabberd2 by default, if yes then how to make it unlimited?

Here is the log:

Request to join group:

```
<presence to='room_18@conference.202.157.76.19/purusottam khandelwal' id='hW11t-156'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'></x><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw='/></presence>
```

Response:

```
<presence from='room_18@conference.202.157.76.19/purusottam khandelwal' to='na_JWtEK8pzlH@202.157.76.19/Smack' type='error' xml:lang='en' id='hW11t-156'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw='/><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></presence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by updating config: max_user_conferences to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Add memory cache to groups on the server

Comment: I have solved the issue by updating config: max_user_conferences to infinity. Thanks for your answer BTW :)

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for posting your solution but put it as an answer pls